# How to resolve classnotfoundexception in Spring with hybris 5.7?

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc, classnotfoundexception, sap-commerce-cloud

I am using Spring MVC framework.I am loading my xml's from project.properties as below:

```
yacceleratorstorefront.additionalWebSpringConfigs.b2bacceleratoraddon=classpath:/b2bacceleratoraddon/web/spring/b2bacceleratoraddon-web-spring.xml,classpath:/b2bacceleratoraddon/web/spring/multi-step-checkout-config.xml,classpath:/b2bacceleratoraddon/web/spring/b2bacceleratoraddon-spring-security-config.xml
yb2bacceleratorstorefront.additionalWebSpringConfigs.b2bacceleratoraddon=classpath:/b2bacceleratoraddon/web/spring/b2bacceleratoraddon-web-spring.xml,classpath:/b2bacceleratoraddon/web/spring/multi-step-checkout-config.xml,classpath:/b2bacceleratoraddon/web/spring/b2bacceleratoraddon-spring-security-config.xml
```

My build is successful but when server is started it is showing below exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.hybris.platform.b2bacceleratoraddon.checkout.steps.validation.impl.DefaultB2BDeliveryAddressCheckoutStepValidator
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:249)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:395)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1349)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1320)
        ... 35 more
Related cause:
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [de.hybris.platform.b2bacceleratoraddon.checkout.steps.validation.impl.DefaultB2BPaymentCheckoutStepValidator] for bean with name 'defaultB2bPaymentMethodCheckoutValidator' defined in class path resource [b2bacceleratoraddon/web/spring/multi-step-checkout-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.hybris.platform.b2bacceleratoraddon.checkout.steps.validation.impl.DefaultB2BPaymentChec
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1328)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:622)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1397)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:434)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:404)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:73)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:243)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:984)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:955)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:466)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:232)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:615)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:434)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.doInitWebApplicationContext(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:145)
        at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:125)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:80)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.hybris.platform.b2bacceleratoraddon.checkout.steps.validation.impl.DefaultB2BPaymentCheckoutStepValidator
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:249)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:395)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1349)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1320)
        ... 35 more
Related cause:
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [de.hybris.platform.b2bacceleratoraddon.checkout.steps.validation.impl.DefaultB2BSummaryCheckoutStepValidator] for bean with name 'defaultB2bSummaryCheckoutValidator' defined in class path resource [b2bacceleratoraddon/web/spring/multi-step-checkout-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.hybris.platform.b2bacceleratoraddon.checkout.steps.validation.impl.DefaultB2BSummaryCheckoutSt
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1328)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:622)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1397)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:434)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:404)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:73)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:243)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:984)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:955)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:466)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:232)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:615)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:434)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.doInitWebApplicationContext(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:145)
        at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:125)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:80)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So can anyone throw some light on it? Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: ClassNotFoundException on `de.hybris.platform.b2bacceleratoraddon.checkout.steps.validation.impl.DefaultB2BPaymentCheckoutStepValidator`. You do not have this class (probably the whole jar) on classpath.

Comment: @GergelyBacso you mean i need to add any jar manually?? i think platform creates the classes automatically at the time of build right?

Comment: how did you create/install your setup? Did you use the installer (and if so which recipe)?
Could you add your localextensions.xml?
Guessing from the class name you are missing a class from an AddOn. The installer recipes usually include the steps to install the AddOn, but if you do the setup manually you will need to invoke the AddOn install command (you can find more info on the hybris wiki for how to install an Addon using ant)